# Simple function to pull field data from a database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm been playing with this for a couple hours now. I'm new to PHP and want to setup a few functions that pull information from a database table by selecting a field if the name of another field checks out.

[database example http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/3770/pn4.png](http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/3770/pn4.png)

This is what I've been playing with. I'm not sure what I'm doing at this point. I've tried so many different combinations of code that I not sure what will work anymore.

```
function getSiteTitle() {
    include("imp/connect.php");
    $siteTitle = "SiteTitle";
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT Value FROM settings WHERE Name = ?");
    $query->bind_param('s', $siteTitle);
    $query->execute();
    $setting = $query->fetch();
    echo $setting;
}
```

I'd be grateful for any help.

**UPDATED: I got it worked, no idea how though really. Here's the updated code:**

```
function getSiteTitle() {
    include("load.php");
    $siteTitle = "SiteTitle";
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT `Value` FROM `Settings` WHERE `Name` = ?') or die (mysqli_error($db));
    $query->bind_param('s', $siteTitle);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($Value);
    $query->fetch();
    echo $Value;        
}

echo getSiteTitle();
```

Comment: Have you tried `echo $setting['Value']`?

Comment: @zdhickman putting `$siteTitle` directly in the query defeats the purpose of prepare/bind_param

Comment: @kalley I get a blank screen, nothing happens. With the code that I originally gave, I do get a 1. But, when I change SiteTitle value to SiteSlogan, I still get the 1.

Comment: To diagnose the problem.... ಠ_ಠ

Comment: use $query->bindColumn("value",$value); after $query->execute statement and then echo $value;

Answer (score 0):

```
please try with the following ,check your connection variables are correct.
<?php
function fetch_data(){
$user="root";
$pass="";
$dsn='mysql:dbname=mydata;host=localhost;';
try{
    $db =new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "connection failed ".$e->getMessage();
}
//replace the code block from $user to end of catch statement because that might be within //your included file connect.php
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT Value FROM settings WHERE Name = ?");
$name="SiteSlogan";//or SiteTitle
$query->bindParam(1,$name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$query->bindColumn("Value",$value);
$query->fetch();
echo $value;
// or you can add more columns in bincolumn like 
//$query->bindColumn("id",$id);
//echo $id;
}

fetch_data();
?>
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours to give it a try and I get this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam() in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions.php on line 7`

Comment: pls check pdo library installed or not through php.ini or <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: Yes, it's installed. I was messing with the code and I got it to work. I updated my original post, maybe you can shed some light on why it was being a pain?